# How to make a token expire after a while? (without jwt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a simple login system that I did with flask.
After logging in, I return to the user a type of token with which the user can send messages like chat at another route.

I would like to expire that token after some time (a minute for example), the token will expire and the user will have to log in again to get a new token.

So my question is, how do you get the token erased or something like that after expiry time?

After the user log in, I save the login time in a dict like this:

```
login_time[datetime.datetime.now()] = data['username']
```

and then I thought of doing something like this before or in the chat route:

```
for time, user in login_time.items():
    if datetime.datetime.now() >= time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30):
        del login_time[time]
```

But I dont know where should I put it and how it will work.

this is a part of the chat route:

```
@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        username = verify_token(data['token']) # Verifying if token is in tokens list
        validate_message(data['message']) # Verifying if message is not empty
        chats.append(username + ": " + data['message'])
        for i, u in login_time.items(): # Not sure about this part
            if i != u:
                abort(400, 'Your token is expired, please login again')
        return jsonify(chats)
```

Comment: you'll need to know for each token what it's expiration date, by db store or it can be part of the token (basically `JWT`), and validate the token by those criteria

Comment: Thanks for your comment, why is this process not possible by storing in to a list:
1) the token.
2) the time when the user logged in.
And from the list knowing all that?
I would be happy if you could explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy to implement solution, if you do not want to use JWT, is :

- When you generate your token, generate the expiration date at the same time
- Log both in a database
- When the user tries to post a message, its token is sent with the message
- check if the token is still valid (either you check if datetime.now() > token_expiration_time or you can even have a script delete every expired token from the database every x minuts and then just check if the token is found in the database or not)
- If the token is expired you redirect the user and ask him to log in again to generate another token.

Comment: Thanks, I took some of your advice and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

when using a token based auth, you'll have to identify and verify the access by that token, i.e identify the client (which user is this) and verify check the token validity like expiration

you can incorporate this data in the token itself (`JWT`)

```
let's say the token is smth like 'token-1571153241', where the number is unix timestamp of expiration
1) parse the expiration timestamp from the token
2) if expiration reached return expiry message, else serve the request
* keep in mind to issue the token with the expiry date
```

or

use any db to store the token's information

```
1) parse the token from the request
2) check the db for the token validity
3) pass or reject based the criteria
```

method 1 is better performance wise, no access to external source (db) is required, but less control of the token attribute, e,g very hard to implement a manual expiration of the token (or change the user privileges access) manually